# Extracting keys and values from nested Object/Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I'm working on dynamic form builder where I've form elements inside row/column grid structure, each of my form elements (object) have a special key named model which defines the field name and value key which defines its value. I have again have nested form which does the same, I need to extract these model and values and make them an Object in case of form repeater it will be an array. Here's a sample format of my form data:

```
[
   {
      "component":"row",
      "attrs":{
         "child_components":[
            {
               "component":"column",
               "attrs":{
                  "child_components":[
                     {
                        "component":"input-text",
                        "attrs":{
                           "child_components":[

                           ],
                           "model":"first_name",
                           "value":"",
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "component":"input-text",
                        "attrs":{
                           "child_components":[

                           ],
                           "model":"last_name",
                           "value":"",
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "component":"column",
               "attrs":{
                  "child_components":[
                     {
                        "component":"form-repeater",
                        "attrs":{
                           "child_components":[
                              {
                                 "component":"column",
                                 "attrs":{
                                    "child_components":[
                                       {
                                          "component":"input-text",
                                          "attrs":{
                                             "child_components":[

                                             ],
                                             "model":"name",
                                             "value": ""
                                          }
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "component":"input-text",
                                          "attrs":{
                                             "child_components":[

                                             ],
                                             "model":"url",
                                             "value":""
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              },
                              {
                                 "component":"column",
                                 "attrs":{
                                    "child_components":[
                                       {
                                          "component":"input-text",
                                          "attrs":{
                                             "child_components":[

                                             ],
                                             "model":"name",
                                             "value":""
                                          }
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "component":"input-text",
                                          "attrs":{
                                             "child_components":[

                                             ],
                                             "model":"url",
                                             "value":""
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ],
                           "model":"links",
                           "value":""
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

To execute this I'm trying to do make a recursive function:

```
findModel(ele) {
  ele.forEach((element) => {
    if(typeof element.attrs.model !== 'undefined') {
      if(element.component === 'form-repeater') {
        let repeater = [];
        element.attrs.child_components.forEach((rep) => {
          let data = this.findModel(rep.attrs.child_components);
          repeater.push(data);
        })
        const repeaterData = {}
        repeaterData[element.attrs.model] = repeater;
        return repeaterData;
      }
      else {
        const data = {}
        data[element.attrs.model] = element.attrs.value;
        return data;
      }
    }
    else {
      if(typeof element.attrs.child_components !== 'undefined' && element.attrs.child_components.length) {
        return this.findModel(element.attrs.child_components);
      }
    }
  })
},
```

And I'm calling this function:

```
let data = findModel(form_data)
console.log(data)
//Always comes undefined.
```

My final format of data will look something like this which I'm unable to achieve:

```
{
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    links: [
        {name: '', url: ''},
        {name: '', url: ''}
    ]
}
```

Help me out in achieving the above format. Any better approach to this is most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Recursion is the right approach. The code could be a bit cleaner, but it's not half bad

Comment: What's your question? If you're looking for code review & improvement suggestions then you probably want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mbdavis my code is not working. Need help in getting the desired format.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Can you help me out?

Comment: With what exactly? You said it works. As @mbdavis mentioned this isnt the right site for code review and your implementation isn't bad I won't say more than that

Comment: @AluanHaddad The recursion function is not working, it is always throwing `undefined` data set. My bad if you got it wrong.

Comment: I guess I missed that part.

Comment: @AluanHaddad My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `undefined` because it does not have a `return` statement. The `return` statements that you have, are returning from the `forEach` callback, which is (obviously) not the same function.

Returning a value in a `forEach` callback is useless, as that value disappears in oblivion. A `forEach` is not intended for that.

You need to:

1. use `.map` instead of `.forEach`
2. return the result of `.map`

So:

```
return ele.map((element) => {
```

Finally, there is a case in your callback logic where you do not return a value: the outer `else` block has a `return` inside an `if` block, but there is no `return` statement for when that inner `if` condition is not true. So there is a theoretical possibility that the callback will return undefined in some cases, meaning that the `.map` will return an array with a potential undefined element.

You should make sure that *all* cases, within the callback code, result in a controlled `return`.